# Crear array a través de ciclo for

Tags: javascript

estoy intentado formar este array con un ciclo for,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Probe con este codigo:

```
var values = [[0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4]];
var valor = new Array(7);
         for(var i=0; i<valor.length; i++) {
            valor[i] = new Array(10);            
           for(var j=0;j<valor[i].length;j++){
             valor[i][j] = values[j][i];
          }
       }

console.log(valor);
```

pero me sale "Error: Cannot read property '0' of undefined",alguna idea para solucionarlo? existe otra forma de armarlo?

El valor de values, es un ejemplo en este codigo, ya que el del array que quiero armar viene definido por un rango de una hoja de calculo, y lo importo como values a javascript. Saludos

Comment: formar el array de la imagen con un ciclo..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para hacer **exactamente** lo que está en la imagen, debería de servirte este código:

```
var values = [[0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4]];
var valor = new Array(7);
for(var i = 0; i < valor.length; i++){
    valor[i] = new Array(10);
    for(var j = 0; j < valor[i].length; j++){
        valor[i][j] = values[j][i+1];
    }
}
```

Comment: Probe pero no funciona... me dice que "undefined" dentro de cada uno. osea values[j][i+1] me da "undefined" para todos

Comment: ¿Estás seguro que tu array values está bien definido con los valores que necesitas? lo digo porque ese error se da ya que no está encontrando un valor en la posición donde está buscando, o sea está indefinida.

Comment: Listo ya lo arregle, tu respuesta me sirvio!